# Last line of textfile not storing correctly into 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

My scanner is not accessing last line of my text file correctly, thus is storing the last line of the text file as all 0's into my 2D array instead of what is actually there. I believe I have provided everything that would give context as to what is going wrong, but if more info is needed I can update this question, thanks in advance.

```
//Creates 2-d array object, stores values from file.
public DominoSort (String fileName) throws java.io.FileNotFoundException{
    this.grid = new int [7][8]; //2-d array to hold values from text file

    Scanner br = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
    String line = br.nextLine();

    int r = 0;
    int c = 0;

    while (br.hasNextLine) {
        String[] row = line.split("\\s+");
        for (String s : row) {
            this.grid[r][c] = Integer.parseInt(s);
            c++;
        }
        line = br.nextLine();
        r++;
        c = 0;
    }

    //this.setS = new ArrayList<>();
    //this.pairMappings = new ArrayList<ArrayList<dominoLocation>>();

    br.close();
}

//Print grid function, prints out the grid
public void printGrid() {
    for(int r = 0; r < this.grid.length; r++) {
        System.out.println("");
        for(int c = 0; c < this.grid[r].length; c++) {
            System.out.print(this.grid[r][c] + " ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("");
}

//Driver for checking
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // String line;
    //System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //get textfile name from user input
    System.out.print("Enter the file name: ");
    String fileName = input.next();

    DominoSort dom = new DominoSort(fileName); //this call populates the 2-d array object
    //dom.solvePuzzle(6);
    dom.printGrid(); //prints 2d array for output

    //dom.solvePuzzle(6);
}
```

text file used for testing / expected output:

```
3 3 4 2 2 0 0 0
4 6 3 6 3 1 4 1
5 5 4 1 2 1 6 5
5 6 0 2 1 1 5 3
5 4 4 2 6 0 2 6
3 0 4 6 6 1 3 1
2 0 3 2 5 0 5 4    {Notice this line}
```

actual output:

```
3 3 4 2 2 0 0 0
4 6 3 6 3 1 4 1
5 5 4 1 2 1 6 5
5 6 0 2 1 1 5 3
5 4 4 2 6 0 2 6
3 0 4 6 6 1 3 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    {this line is not right}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies within the nested while/for loop. It reaches the end condition before all the lines are read. (The nextLine() method doesn't have any more lines before you read the last line). You can see this by putting an extra 1 or 2 lines in your file at the very end, making it show the last lines.
There are a few ways to fix it, one of them is by just adding on an extra for loop after the while loop to compute the last line individually:

```
    while (br.hasNextLine()) {

        String[] row = line.split("\\s+");

        for (String s : row) {
            this.grid[r][c] = Integer.parseInt(s);
            c++;
        }

        line = br.nextLine();
        r++;
        c = 0;
    }

    String[] row = line.split("\\s+");
    for (String s : row) {
        this.grid[r][c] = Integer.parseInt(s);
        c++;
    }
```

or alternatively, don't increment the line on the first run:

```
        while (br.hasNextLine()) {

            String[] row = line.split("\\s+");

            for (String s : row) {
                this.grid[r][c] = Integer.parseInt(s);
                c++;
            }

            if (r != 0) 
                line = br.nextLine();

            r++;
            c = 0;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! The first approach worked perfectly.